# Running an executable from a symbolic link, when the executable expects it's config files to be in it's directory

Tags: software-installation

I want to install `p0f` 3.08 (https://github.com/p0f/p0f) globally on my Ubuntu box. The repos only have the old version so I want to install it from `github`.

I ran `git clone` then `make` and the program compiled successfully. I can run it fine from that directory (`/opt/p0f-3.08b`), but I want to run it from anywhere.

So I made a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /opt/p0f-3.08b/p0f /usr/sbin/p0f
```

I can now run it from a terminal anywhere with `p0f`, but I get this error:

```
SYSTEM ERROR : Cannot open 'p0f.fp' for reading.
```

This is because `p0f` expects to have `p0f.fp` in the same directory as it is being run, which isn't the case if I'm not in the install directory `/opt/p0f-3.08b`.

Is there a way to solve this without adding a symbolic link for `p0f.fp`? That seems very ugly, especially as a program could have dozens of these files.

Comment: Not an answer, but it seems to me (without having that software to look at) that a wrapper script would be needed; something like: `cd /opt/p0f-3.08b && exec ./p0f`

Comment: The `-f` option can be used to specify the location of `p0f.fp`